# Checking vulnerabilities in python code with bandit using jenkins pipeline

Tags: python-2.7, jenkins, bandit, bandit-python

Can anyone help me with this in jenkins:

1. Install the required jenkins plugins .
2. Configure your job to scan only python files .
3. Using bandit, scan only the python files of the directory- "examples"  and publish the results in html format . And the report is named as report.html .And below is the command I used -

   bandit -r examples/*.py -f html -o report.html
4. And when clicked on the build now, it is getting failed . Can any help me with this : how to install bandit in a jenkins pipeline ? and pip is also not working in jenkins . I am executing in shell command(os-linux2,pyhthon-2.7 system configuration)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

use as below and try

bandit -r "examples/*.py" -f html -o report.html